# Need help adding component in angular

Tags: angular

I am a beginner with angular.

I have existing code that works.  There are two screens documents/bydocument and documents/byfacility.  I want to add a third one, documents/bytype.  What I did was copy the directories associated with bydocument into bytype and modified all the files changing byydocument or ByDocument to bytype or ByType.  I then also modified app.module.ts and wherever it had the ByDocument I copied that line and changed it to ByType.  I also added the block of code by copying the bydocument and made it bytype.

The problem is that while everything worked without the modifications in app.module.ts, except that it didn't go to the bytype page and instead went to the home page, it didn't work at all with the modified app.module.ts file.  It just gave a blank screen with no errors indicated anywhere, even in the console tab of the debugger. (Using Chrome).

What do I have to do to add whatever is needed for this Component to make it work properly?

Comment: Have you added the correct routing?

Comment: I think so.  That is in the modifications I mentioned above.  They were all mirror of the bydocuments and changed properly.  Is there some angular thing that needs to be done?

Comment: can you post your routing module as well?

Comment: Could you please provide some code of app.module.ts and app.routing.ts to your original post?

Comment: Newish to stack overflow.  How do add code now?

Comment: I do not see an app.routing.ts.  I see an app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Make this your bible and read thoroughly: https://angular.io/docs. That should solve all your problems but if you still have questions ask.

Comment: app-routing.module.ts it is then. You can edit your question by clicking 'Edit' and you can add code blocks in the editor.

Comment: They come out unformatted.  Also, how do you go to a new line when adding a comment?

Comment: hightlight the code part and click ctrl+k

Comment: I made some progress on this.  I used the ng g component ..dirtree.../DocumentByName.  It created the directory tree where I wanted it as document-by-name and put the four files in there and also modified the app.module.ts.

Comment: (continued) What worked before clicking it no longer works.  I put a breakpoint in sidebar.component.ts navigationMenu and no matter what I click on the menu,  I always get the proper route. Nothing processes onto the screen though.  I also copied over copies of the bydeparment files, suitably modified to change to bytype, into the created files and the same problem appears.  Is there something more I need to do besides just the ng g component stuff?